# SQL Query GroupBy with date parameter

Tags: sql, group-by

Suppose I have a table, TeamRatings, that looks something like this

```
|---Team----|--ValuationDate--|-Rating-|

|--Saints---|---10/15/2012----|---81.1-|  
|--Broncos--|---10/15/2012----|---91.1-|  
|--Ravens---|---10/16/2012----|--101.1-|  
|--Broncos--|---10/22/2012----|---82.1-|  
|--Ravens---|---10/22/2012----|---83.1-|  
|--Saints---|---10/29/2012----|---84.1-|  
|--Broncos--|---10/28/2012----|---85.1-|
|--Ravens---|---10/29/2012----|---86.1-|
```

Also, it is assumed that a team's rating remains unchanged until they play a new game, (representing a new record).  E.g. The Broncos' rating on date 10/21/2012 is assumed to be 102.8

I want a query with a date parameter, that will return one record per team represnting that team's most recent game prior to the date specified.  For instance,

If I input 10/23/2012 as my date parameter, the query should return

```
|---Team---|-ValuationDate---|-Rating-|

|--Saints--|---10/15/2012----|---81.1-|  
|--Broncos-|---10/22/2012----|---82.1-|  
|--Ravens--|---10/22/2012----|---83.1-|
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MS SQL Server 2005 or greater you can use a cte with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH x 
     AS (SELECT team, 
                valuationdate, 
                rating, 
                rn = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY team 
                         ORDER BY valuationdate DESC) 
         FROM   teamratings 
         WHERE  valuationdate < @DateParam) 
SELECT team, 
       valuationdate, 
       rating 
FROM   x 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more general query like this:

```
select Team, x.ValuationDate, Rating
from TeamRatings inner join
(
 select Team, max(ValuationDate) as ValuationDate
 from TeamRatings 
 where ValuationDate < @dateParameter
 group by Team
) x on TeamRatings.Team = x.Team and TeamRatings.ValuationDate = x.ValuationDate
```